Cardinalidad Mínima y máxima (1,1) con pata de gallo
Lucidchart dice que está usando una notación pata de gallo, y veo a muchos haciéndolo, indicando que una cardinalidad mínima y máxima (1,1) con pata de gallo es una raya horizontal con 2 palitos.
En cambio, desde hace 20 años y otras fuentes bibliográficas dicen que es una raya horizontal con 1 palito.
Necesito que alguien me arroje luz al respecto. ¿Son dos versiones diferentes de las mismas cardinalidades o son diferentes cardinalidades con diferentes restricciones?. gracias.
Adjunto comparativa de notaciones. En ella dicen que la que usa 2 palitos es la ADW.


Tanto la notación con "un palito" como la de "dos palitos" representan la misma cardinalidad (1,1), indicando una relación uno a uno obligatoria. Sin embargo, diferentes herramientas y metodologías, como Lucidchart y ADW, utilizan variaciones visuales en los diagramas ER. Ambos estilos son correctos, solo que pertenecen a estándares distintos. Lo importante es que ambas notaciones comunican la misma restricción de cardinalidad, por ende podés utilizar la que mejor se ajuste a las convenciones de tu equipo o herramienta de modelado preferida.

Muchas gracias. ¿Podrías indicarme el nombre completo ADW?. No encuentro bibliografía al respecto. Además, ¿no sabrías de alguna comparativa más completa que esta? Quisiera irme familiarizando con las distintas notaciones. Gracias.

Revisar [answer], saludos.
